# Calabi-Yau manifolds and compactification of extra dimensions in M-theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification, calabi-yau

I just finished learning M(atrix) theory and the basics of the [compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_%28physics%29) of extra dimensions.

The extra 6 dimensions of superstring theory can be compactified on 3 Calabi-Yau manifolds (because 6 real dimensions means 3 complex dimensions).

However, when it comes to [M-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory), one cannot compactify on 3.5 Calabi-Yau manifolds, so after compactifying 6 dimensions, where does the extra 1 dimension go? Is it just compactified on a circle, or something like that?

Comment: For clarity, there are CY's of complex dimension two, three, etc., not just one.

Comment: Keyword in this context: [$G_2$-manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2_manifold#Connections_to_physics).

Comment: See on the nLab at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-theory+on+G2-manifolds